# Tengo este error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, php7

Tengo parte de codigo en php

```
$accion = $_POST['accion'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

if($accion === 'crear') {
    //codigo para crear usuarios

    //hashear contraseña
    $opciones = array(
        'cost' => 12
    );

    $hash_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);
    //importamos conexion
    include '../funciones/conexion.php';
    try{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, contraseña) VALUES (?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $hash_password);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->affected_rows > 0){
            $respuesta = array(
                "respuesta" => "correcto",
                "id_insertado" => $stmt->insert_id,
                "tipo" => $accion
            );
        } else{
            $respuesta = array(
                "respuesta" => "error"
            );
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $respuesta = array(
            'error' => $e->getMessage()
        );
    }
}
```

La cual inserta datos en la base de datos y tambien manda un array con ciertos atributos a una clase JS 
esta es la clase

```
function validarRegistro(e){
e.preventDefault();

var usuario = document.querySelector('#usuario').value,
    password = document.querySelector('#password').value,
    tipo = document.querySelector('#tipo').value;

if(usuario === '' || password === ''){
    swal({
        type:'error',
        title:'Error!',
        text:'Ambos campos son obligatorios!!!!'
    })
}
else{

    // datos para el servidor
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('usuario', usuario);
    datos.append('password', password);
    datos.append('accion', tipo);

    // creamos llamado a AJAX

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //Abrimos la conexion

    xhr.open('POST', 'inc/modelos/modelo-admin.php', true);

    // retorno de datos

    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status === 200){
            var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            console.log(respuesta);
            if(respuesta.respuesta === 'correcto'){
                if(respuesta.tipo === 'crear'){
                    swal ({

                        title: 'Usuario creado',
                        text: 'El usuario se creo correctamente',
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                }else{
                    swal({
                        type:'error',
                        title:'Error!',
                        text:'Hubo un error'
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //enviamos la peticion

    xhr.send(datos);

}
```

ese array contiene varios datos, uno de ellos es el que se llama respuesta que debe mandar si es correcto o incorrecto todo lo que se mandado, el detalle es que se quiere obtener en tipo JSON.
Cuando inserta en la base de datos lo hace correctamente, pero me da ese error y la alerta no la muestra, sospecho que estoy mandando mal el array que se convierte en JSON pero no se como deberia de mandarlo o el problema sera en otra parte del codigo?

Comment: ¿Que es lo que te devuelve `console.log(respuesta)`?

Comment: : JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Literalmente no me devuelve nada, y me da ese error